# Multiple Forms in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I realize that ASP.NET is only designed to [support a single form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164151.aspx).  What I am confused about is what is the appropriate method for coding multiple "forms" on a .NET page (I have a login form at the top of the page, via the Site.Master and other forms will appear on any given page).  Am I supposed to respond differently?  It doesn't really make a whole lot of sense.  I would appreciate it if someone could clarify.  Thanks.

P.S.  I am currently developing on .NET 2.0 although I plan to move to .NET 3.5 soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Nearly all ASP.NET Web Forms post back to the same page.* Unless you are working on some strange outlier (which your question doesn't indicate), you just use one form tag around the entire document, and use event hookups to your controls to handle the various instances.

For example, you can have three buttons that act as Submit buttons, one for each "form" but all inside that same `form` tag, and each one will call its respective event. This behavior is standard and handled by ASP.NET for you; all you have to do is write the event handlers and wire them up.

Comment: Okay.  I was wondering if this would work.  Is this the appropriate solution (asking the rest of SO)?  Is there any downsides to doing this?

Comment: This is the intended use of ASP.NET. If you want to have your button "submit" to another page, you can hand over control of the page by redirecting using server-side code.

Comment: Alright.  Thanks!  It does strike me as a little odd that I just put a big "form" inside the Site.Master file (I have to since it references a specific control which requires a form).  Kind of rubs my "programming self" the wrong way.  But, I am new to web programming, so I might be missing something very subtle (or obvious...haha).  Thanks for your help.

Comment: If this style of coding bothers you (and it bothers a lot of people :-) you can consider using the ASP.NET MVC. Version 1 has been released, version 2 is in release candidate. I haven't touched Web Forms in over a year now due to the MVC framework.

Comment: Interesting (and more of what I was looking for).  Thank you.  BTW, I did find *one* problem with wrapping everything in a form.  The default [Enter] key press does not go with the control I am necessarily in (it defaults to the first button on the page).

Comment: Wrap what you want to be forms in asp:Panels, where you can specify the DefaultButton property.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by a logon form. Are you doing some special ajax stuff?

You should be dividing any logical "form" as you call it into its own usercontrol.

http://www.asp101.com/lessons/usercontrols.asp

When dealing with aspx pages, think of the form on the page the same way you think of the body tag.

Comment: No, not doing anything special AJAX-wise.  And, my login "stuff" is a separate user control.  But, it still requires a form and when I was putting the login control into any of my ASPX documents, and I had another form already in the ASPX document, my site would crash.  That's what confused me.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, I would hand-code the login form at the top to submit to a separate login.aspx page.  Leave the rest of the page to the other form's own purpose.

Comment: Why not use the login controls that are part of .net 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

by default you can't, it's how the whole webforms technology works (MVC would probobly fix this in the newest versions).

So really it depends on what you want the "two forms" to do.  For example, there's no issue with having login & search on one page, as each button has its own click event and go from there.  If you wanted a second aspx page to process one of them, you could collect values and pass them through a response.redirect or some other hacky solution.